# Remove JSON Object in jqGrid Post Data

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, jqgrid

I have got a web page with the Filters with two buttons which loads the data for jqGrid.

When a user clicks on 'Filter', I generated postData json object and sends it to the server.  That's working fine.

But when a user clicks on 'Clear', I want to clear the filter and re-load all data from jqGrid.  That's where I am stuck at.

[image]

This is how my Filters are posted to the server.
[image]

jQuery codes for the button clicks are here:

```
    $('#btnFilter').click(function (event) {

        var filterObject = { 
            RecordID: $('#RecordID').val() 
            , Student: $('#Student').val() 
        }

        $("#jqGrid").jqGrid().setGridParam({ postData: { Filters: filterObject }, page: 1 }).trigger("reloadGrid");
    });

    $('#btnClear').click(function (event) {         

        var filterObject = {};
        $("#jqGrid").jqGrid().setGridParam({ postData: { Filters: filterObject }, page: 1 }).trigger("reloadGrid");
    });
```

Even though, I did set null JSON object for the filterObject with { }, the browser caches the Filters value and I couldn't manage to remove them.  In the below screenshot, we can see the Ajax Post and objects sent to the server when 'Clear' button is clicked.

[image]

I would like to know how I could remove that Filters { } objects when 'Clear' is clicked.  Or if there is a better way to achieve what I want, could you please suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very easy to do if you understand that jqGrid hold all parameters in one internal object. You can use

```
var p = $("#jqGrid").jqGrid("getGridParam");
```

to get all options of jqGrid. You can modify the properties directly in the object. The `postData` are accessible via `p.postData`. If you need to modify only `postData` the you can use

```
var postData = $("#jqGrid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData");
```

to get **the reference** to `postData` property of the internal `postData` object (`p.postData`). Thus you *don't need to use `setGridParam`* to modify the data. To remove `Filters` property you, which you previously set by

```
$("#jqGrid").jqGrid("setGridParam", { postData: { Filters: filterObject }, page: 1 });
```

you can use

```
var postData = $("#jqGrid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData");
delete postData.Filters;
```

Comment: I have never seen this 'delete' keywords in Javascript.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is wondering, you can pass null to nullify the previous JSON object.  The complete code is here.

```
$("#jqGrid").jqGrid().setGridParam({ postData: { Filters: null}, page: 1 }).trigger("reloadGrid");
```